# What happens if you update the column of a Delta table by which it is partitioned?

Tags: merge, partitioning, delta-lake

What happens if you update the column of a Delta table by which it is partitioned?
Does it degrade Write performance substantially?
I am trying to find out which I haven't been able to so far from the docs whether lets say if we have underlying parquet, does Delta rebuild new files without the updated rows for the existing partitions OR is it virtually handled through transaction log entries?

Comment: what do you mean by update? Update value?

Comment: Yes @AlexOtt, update the value of the column for some rows lets say using the MERGE operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get this information from the history. For example, here is the data from `operationsMetric` column after execution of the update operation on the partition column. As you see, it rewrites files:

```json
{
  "numRemovedFiles": "5", 
  "numCopiedRows": "0", 
  "numAddedChangeFiles": "0", 
  "executionTimeMs": "478", 
  "scanTimeMs": "34", 
  "numAddedFiles": "5", 
  "numUpdatedRows": "5", 
  "rewriteTimeMs": "444"
}
```

and if you check file names, then you see that they are different.

Comment: Thank you Alex. It is good to know Delta actually rewrites files. This tells me frequent updates to a partition column may not be a good idea.

Comment: But do you really need to have this partition column if you're planning to update it? Really, with Delta, need for partition columns is lower compared to Parquet